# Hover is not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to scale the button for the hover but it's not working. I can't find out the main issue. Here is the code:

```
.lead,
.lead:hover {
padding: 17px 50px;
color: #2e7c37;
background-color: #ffdc10;
font-family: "Roboto", Sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 500;
border:none;
transition: all .3s 
}

.lead:hover,
.lead:focus,
.lead:active {
transform: scale(1.2);
}

.site-content a {
    color: #2e7d32 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important
}
```

What is wrong? Why it's not working?

Comment: Use code snippet, include html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/wsmhb8es/ I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @RezaSaadati change the div with a span and see ;) ... am pretty sure this is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `display` for links (`<a>`) is `inline`. To allow sizing and transform, you need to reset `display` to any other value. Here `inline-block` should be fine .

```
.lead {display:inline-block;}
```

Also, to react on hover, a link needs to have the attribute `href` , even if empty.

Next time, share also your HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define `lead:hover` class two times. Just make sure you only define `lead:hover` class one time. All the properties of `.lead` class are automatically inherited to the `.lead:hover` state.